# Умножение Time и INT (Float) в MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server

В базе есть поле типа TIME (некая наработка), ее необходимо умножить на число типа int, float. Но я никак не могу найти как можно получить TotalHours из TIME. Или преобразовать тип TYPE к чему-либо, кроме VARCHAR.

Comment: Нашел вот такой вариант:
DECLARE @TimeValue TIME = '12:00:00';

SELECT CAST(CAST(@TimeValue AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT) * 10;

Только теперь надо обратно в TIME. Слишком много CAST'ов.

Answer (score 1):

Искренне рекомендую справочные данные по работе с MS SQL искать в MSDN - отличнейшая справка, мне очень помогает.

Ответ на ваш вопрос есть здесь: [Типы данных и функции даты и времени (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186724.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант можно воспользоваться DATEPART(HOUR, @TimeValue)